# How do I fade in ckeditor with jquery?

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I am building an ajax app, and I want the ckeditor to fade in or out for a nice smooth effect.But no matter what I try, the editor appears or disappears instantly.I use the following code to create the editor, any ideas how to do the fadeIn?

```
$("#txt_maingb").ckeditor(function(){},{toolbar:myToolbarConfig_FULL});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var textarea = $("#txt_maingb");
textarea.ckeditor(function(){},{toolbar:myToolbarConfig_FULL});
$('#cke_editor1').hide().fadeIn(500);
```

Comment: It didn't work, `$("#txt_maingb").hide().ckeditor(function(){},{toolbar:myToolbarConfig_FULL}).fadeIn(2000);`

Comment: @aoi See update, also the code you posted wasn't the code I did.